# Mixing Redux with useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I read that this is theoretically OK. In my small use case, I'm running into an issue, where mixing those technologies leads to double re-rendering.

First, when redux dispatch is executed and some components use a prop via useSelector. Then, after the functional component is already re-rendered, a useEffect hook is being applied which updates the state of some property. This update re-triggers the render again.

E.g. the below console log prints out twice in my case.

Question: should I remove the useEffect and useState and integrate it into redux' store?

```
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import React from "react";


const Dashboard = (props) => {
    const selFilters = useSelector((state) => state.filter.selectedDashboardFilters);
    const [columns, setColumns] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
            let newColumns = getColumns();
            setColumns(newColumns)
        }, [selFilters]
    )
    
    console.log("RENDER")
    
    return (
        <h1>{columns.length}</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem. I created a custom hook to fetch data from API and set it to a Redux state. The problem is that I enter in a loop. Could you solve your issue?

Answer (score -1):

If `columns` needs to be recomputed whenever `selFilters` changes, you almost certainly shouldn't be recomputing it within your component. If `columns` is computed from `selFilters`, then you likely don't need to store it as state at all. Instead, you could use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create a `getColumns()` selector that derives the columns from the state whenever the relevant state changes. For example:

```js
const getColumns = createSelector(
  state => state.filter.selectedDashboardFilters,
  selFilters => {
    // Compute `columns` here
    // ...
    return columns
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Reselect looks interesting - I'll surely make use of it down the line. In this particular case, the columns list needs to be stateful, as it updates itself after the initialization. I reckon I'll have to move it to a reducer in this case (?)

*Accidently clicked down arrow and can't undo it. It should say +1!

Comment: Yeah, without knowing more about your app I can't know what exactly the best way for you to do it would be. You could absolutely store both in the state and just update them together. It depends entirely on what this data is and how your app works.